# Неблокирующий параллельный алгоритм поиска максимума и его индекса

Tags: java, concurrency, распараллеливание, atomic

Существует ли неблокирующий параллельный алгоритм поиска максимального элемента массива а также его индекса? Есть такая реализация,

```
AtomicInteger atomicMin = new AtomicInteger(99999);
AtomicInteger atomicMax = new AtomicInteger(-99999);
AtomicInteger atomicMinIndex = new AtomicInteger();
AtomicInteger atomicMaxIndex = new AtomicInteger();
AtomicInteger atomicIndex = new AtomicInteger(0);

IntStream.range(0, arr.length).parallel().forEach(i -> {
    int oldMin;
    int newMin;
    int oldMax;
    int newMax;
    int oldMinIndex;
    int newMinIndex;
    int oldMaxIndex;
    int newMaxIndex;

    do {
        oldMin = atomicMin.get();
        oldMax = atomicMax.get();
        oldMinIndex = atomicMinIndex.get();
        oldMaxIndex = atomicMaxIndex.get();

        newMin = arr[i] < oldMin ? arr[i] : oldMin;
        newMax = arr[i] > oldMax ? arr[i] : oldMax;
        newMinIndex = arr[i] < oldMin ? i : oldMinIndex;
        newMaxIndex = arr[i] > oldMax ? i : oldMaxIndex;

    } while (!atomicMin.compareAndSet(oldMin, newMin) ||
            !atomicMax.compareAndSet(oldMax, newMax) ||
            !atomicMinIndex.compareAndSet(oldMinIndex, newMinIndex) ||
            !atomicMaxIndex.compareAndSet(oldMaxIndex, newMaxIndex));
});
```

но смущает вот этот участок кода

```
while (!atomicMin.compareAndSet(oldMin, newMin) ||
            !atomicMax.compareAndSet(oldMax, newMax) ||
            !atomicMinIndex.compareAndSet(oldMinIndex, newMinIndex) ||
            !atomicMaxIndex.compareAndSet(oldMaxIndex, newMaxIndex))
```

тут по сути операция обновления максимума и его индекса не атомарна, то есть другой поток может записать другое значение индекса элемента, в результате максимальный элемент будет найден правильно, а его индекс - нет.

Подскажите, это корректный алгоритм и как в этом можно формально убедиться?

**Upd.** Переписал вот так, по идее теперь сомнений быть не должно

```
    public static AtomicSearchResult getMax(final Array array, final Comparator<Integer> comparator) {
        if (array.size() < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array must contain at least one element");
        }
        AtomicSearchResult searchResult = new AtomicSearchResult(array.get(0), 0);

        IntStream.range(0, array.size()).parallel().forEach((i) -> {
            int currentElement = array.get(i);
            AtomicSearchResult.SearchResult currentSearchResultValue;
            do {
                currentSearchResultValue = searchResult.get();
            } while (comparator.compare(currentElement, currentSearchResultValue.getValue()) > 0 && !searchResult.compareAndSet(currentSearchResultValue, currentElement, i));
        });
        return searchResult;
    }

    public final static class AtomicSearchResult {
        private final AtomicLong max; // stores index and value as 64 bit long in such format - <32 bit of max value><32 bit of corresponding index>. See method 'convertToLong'

        public AtomicSearchResult(int maxValue, int index) {
            max = new AtomicLong(convertToLong(maxValue, index));
        }

        public SearchResult get() {
            long currentValue = max.get();
            return new SearchResult(getMaxValue(currentValue), getElementIndex(currentValue));
        }

        private int getMaxValue(long value) {
            return (int) (value >>> 32);
        }

        private int getElementIndex(long value) {
            return (int) (value & 0xFFFFFFFFL);
        }

        public boolean compareAndSet(SearchResult expected, int actualMaxValue, int actualMaxIndex) {
            return compareAndSet(expected.getValue(), expected.getIndex(), actualMaxValue, actualMaxIndex);
        }

        public boolean compareAndSet(int expectedMaxValue, int expectedMaxIndex, int actualMaxValue, int actualMaxIndex) {
            long expectedLong = convertToLong(expectedMaxValue, expectedMaxIndex);
            long actualLong = convertToLong(actualMaxValue, actualMaxIndex);
            return max.compareAndSet(expectedLong, actualLong);
        }

        private long convertToLong(int value, int index) {
            return ((long) value << 32) | index;
        }

        @Data
        public final static class SearchResult {
            private final int value;
            private final int index;
        }
    }
```

Что думаете?

Comment: Вам тут стримы всё портят) вашу лямбду будут дергать на каждый элемент и поэтому каждый раз надо дергать атомики что фактически сделает кеш процессоров бесполезным, а регистровые оптимизации невозможными. Тут нужно разбить массив на части (в идеале по количеству процов), и каждую часть пройти обычным циклом с локальными переменными, а в конце выбрать максимум из полученных результатов

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Делаете N потоков, каждый из которых ищет индекс максимального элемента на своем участке массива, затем выбираете максимальный из найденных N максимумов - это и будет максимальный элемент во всем массиве. Любители buzzwords и bullshit bingo наверное сразу бы вспомнили про map-reduce, а на деле все элементарно, для потоков даже синхронизация не требуется, надо только подождать, пока они все окончат работу:

```
public class t_Main
{
    private static final class
    t_MaxFinder implements Runnable
    {
        private final int m_begin_index;
        private final int m_end_index;
        private final int m_thread_index;
        private final int [] m_items;
        private final int [] m_max_indexes;

        public t_MaxFinder
        (
            final int begin_index
        ,   final int items_count
        ,   final int [] items
        ,   final int [] max_indexes
        ,   final int thread_index
        )
        {
            m_begin_index = begin_index;
            m_end_index = begin_index + items_count;
            m_thread_index = thread_index;
            m_items = items;
            m_max_indexes = max_indexes;
            return;
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            int max_index = m_begin_index;
            int max_value = m_items[m_begin_index];
            for (int index = m_begin_index; index < m_end_index; ++index)
            {
                final int value = m_items[index];
                if (max_value < value)
                {
                    max_index = index;
                    max_value = value;
                }
            }
            m_max_indexes[m_thread_index] = max_index;
            System.out.printf
            (
                "thread %d (%d - %d, %d) max %d at %d\n"
            ,   m_thread_index, m_begin_index, m_end_index
            ,   m_end_index - m_begin_index, max_value, max_index
            );
            return;
        }
    }

    private static int
    Find_MaxIndex
    (
        final int [] items
    ,   final int threads_count
    ) throws InterruptedException
    {
        final int [] max_indexes = new int[threads_count];
        {
            java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService pool = java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads_count);
            {
                int items_count = items.length / threads_count;
                int begin_index = 0;
                for (int thread_index = 0; thread_index < threads_count; ++thread_index)
                {
                    if (thread_index == (threads_count - 1))
                    {
                        items_count += items.length % threads_count;
                    }
                    pool.execute(new t_MaxFinder(begin_index, items_count, items, max_indexes, thread_index));
                    begin_index += items_count;
                }
            }
            pool.shutdown();
            pool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
        int max_index = max_indexes[0];
        int max_value = items[max_index];
        for (int max_index_index = 1; max_index_index < max_indexes.length; ++max_index_index)
        {
            final int index = max_indexes[max_index_index];
            final int value = items[index];
            if (max_value < value)
            {
                max_index = index;
                max_value = value;
            }
        }
        return max_index;
    }

    public static void main
    (
        String [] args
    ) throws InterruptedException
    {
        final long seed = 42;
        final int threads_count = 3;
        final int items_count = 20;
        final int item_max = 100;
        final int [] items = new int[items_count];
        {
            final java.util.Random rd = new java.util.Random(seed);
            for (int item_index = 0; item_index < items.length; ++item_index)
            {
                items[item_index] = rd.nextInt(item_max);
                System.out.println(items[item_index]);
            }
        }
        final int max_index = Find_MaxIndex(items, threads_count);
        System.out.printf("result max %d at %d", items[max_index], max_index);
    }
}
```